# 500 internal server error on magento 2 live server website is not going to be launched

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

The server encountered an `internal error` or `misconfiguration` and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at `webmaster@shamareen.com` to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log